# C# DllImport and Marshaling char**

Tags: c#, char, dllimport

I'm working in c# and I need to use this function from a c++ dll:

```
extern "C" char   IMPEXP __stdcall service_GetParameter ( const char* parameter, const int value_lenght, char** value );
```

I have used it in c++ code as follow:

```
char *val = new char[256];
service_GetParameter("firmware_version", 255, &val);
AnsiString FirmwareVersion = val;
delete[] val;
```

How can I import this function and use it in c#?

Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI, I think your C++ is a bit dodgy. What `service_GetParameter` is doing is returning a pointer to characters via `* value`. So your `delete[] val` is deleting the pointer that is returned, not the original memory you allocated. You'd be better off without the `new` and `delete` and simply writing `char* val = 0`.

Comment: I don't think there's a valid answer without knowing more about the `service_GetParameter` function. Does it allocate the memory? Or does it maybe return a pointer to some internal string? Why use a `char **` if the caller has to allocate the memory?

Comment: service_GetParameter don't allocate the memory. The caller must allocate the memory, call the service_GetParameter and free the memory (with delete[] in C++).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this function allocates memory and makes the caller responsible for freeing it, I'm afraid you'll have to manage this manually: Declare the parameter as a `ref IntPtr` and use the methods of the `Marshal` class to get a String with a copy of the pointed data.

Then call the appropriate function for freeing the memory (as Dirk said, we can't say more about this without more information on the function).

If it really must be allocated before calling, it should be something looking like this:

```
[DllImport("yourfile.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern sbyte service_GetParameter ( String parameter, Int32 length, ref IntPtr val);

public static string ServiceGetParameter(string parameter, int maxLength)
{
    string ret = null;
    IntPtr buf = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(maxLength+1);
    try
    {
        Marshal.WriteByte(buf, maxLength, 0); //Ensure there will be a null byte after call
        IntPtr buf2 = buf;
        service_GetParameter(parameter, maxLength, ref buf2);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(buf == buf2, "The C++ function modified the pointer, it wasn't supposed to do that!");
        ret = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buf);
    }
    finally { Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(buf); }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: service_GetParameter don't allocate the memory. The caller must allocate the memory, call the service_GetParameter and free the memory (with delete[] in C++)

Comment: So why does it take a pointer to the pointer??  ...Well, anyway if that's so you may be able to marshal the parameter as a StringBuilder, though that's not guaranteed. But at least, wrapping the call in a C# function that uses the `Marshal` class should work (though it may be slower than a successful automatic marshaling).

Comment: I don't know why take a pointer to pointer. Can you help me with some code exemple?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with something like this:

```
[DllImport("yourfile.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi]
public static extern Int32 service_GetParameter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String szParameter, Int32 value_length, [Out] StringBuilder sbValue);
```

Comment: Of course, it's more complicated if `service_GetParameter` allocates memory.

Comment: @Medinoc Why?  Isn't that still the C++ method's responsibility?  This is just a call.  The use of StringBuilder ensures a copied value and not a reference to any original memory.

Comment: By "allocates memory", I meant "returns a pointer to allocated memory that the caller is responsible for freeing". If this is the case, the C# code will leak said memory. If this isn't (say, it returns a pointer to inside a common buffer that's the responsibility of some other code) then there's no problem.

Comment: @Medinoc I would agree with that.  And I'm no P/invoke guru, but I believe that is what StringBuilder does for you...the marshaling copies the memory as opposed to sharing it.

Comment: The marshaling copies, but I seriously doubt that it would delete the original returned by the C function. It has no idea whether to use `delete[]`, or `CoTaskMemFree`, or any other memory deallocation function.

Comment: @Medinoc You may be right.  But that's assuming that the original C++ function just leaves it hanging, right?  I mean, shouldn't it already be cleaning that up if it's allocating it?

Comment: It can't clean up before it returns, so from its signature, either it hands responsibility over to the caller (which would cause a leak), or it keeps its stuff in a global variable that's cleaned up later by another C++ function (which wouldn't cause a leak). Note that responsibility transfers are common: Anything which works on BSTRs does this, for example.

Comment: @Medinoc Good point.  If that's the case, then I'm afraid we're getting beyond my level of skill with this topic.