# How to marshall LPSTR** in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling

I have a method in unmaged COM object which I'm trying to marshall:

```
STDMETHOD(SomeMethod)(LPSTR** items, INT* numOfItems) = 0;
```

But I can't figure out the right way to marshal out LPSTR** items. It's supposed to be a list of items. However if try to do something like this:

```
[PreserveSig] 
int SomeMethod([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]ref StringBuilder items, ref uint numOfItems);
```

I only get the very first letter of the very first item and nothing else.

How can I marshal LPSTR** variable correctly?

Comment: This should be more like `StringBuilder[]`. You can marshal that parameter manually, see e.g [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16857034/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr, I tried using StringBuilder[] but in this case I'm getting this error: "Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock'  occurred". Will take a look at the link you provided though.

Comment: What is the marshalling direction? In, Out, Both?

Comment: @arbiter, Out as it supposed to return items and number of the said items.

Comment: It is a *very* unfriendly function, quite hard to call reliably from a C++ program.  That never gets better when you pinvoke.  It wants to return an array of strings and tell you how many elements are in the array.  What is not obvious at all, not to the pinvoke marshaller either, is how you are supposed to destroy the array again.  You have to use `out IntPtr` and use Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi to recover the strings.  Nobody can tell you what to do next.  Call it a million times in a test program to ensure you don't leak memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot check it right now, but signature should look like this:

```
[PreserveSig]
int SomeMethod(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeParamIndex = 1)] out string[] items,
    out int numOfItems);
```

Of course, it is doesn't help, you can always perform manual marshalling via [Marshal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal(v=vs.110).aspx) class (as Sinatr suggested).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication49
{
    class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
        public struct UnmanagedStruct 
        { 
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)] 
            public IntPtr[] listOfStrings; 
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UnmanagedStruct uStruct = new UnmanagedStruct();
            IntPtr strPtr = uStruct.listOfStrings[0];

            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            while (strPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                string readStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(strPtr);
                data.Add(readStr);
                strPtr += readStr.Length; //I think it should be Length + 1 to include '\0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```